Bootstrap 5 popover html content
I am using Bootstrap 5 popover and it could not show the HTML content that I need.
I followed this link as a solution:
How to add html tag attribute in bootstrap 5 popover setAttribute()?
It was working for some of the HTML attributes like for example:
data-bs-content="<h1>Hello</h1>"
But what I need to display is a table:
<table>
<tr>
  <td>A班</td>
  <td>B班</td>
  <td>C班</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Joy</td>
</tr>

My HTML:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger testing" data-bs-toggle="popover" 
data-bs-content ="
<table>
<tr>
  <td>A班</td>
  <td>B班</td>
  <td>C班</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Joy</td>
</tr>
    </table>
" 
title="Popover title"
data-bs-trigger="hover"
>Click to toggle popover</button>

And the Javascript:
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,

   // options object as a second param
   {
      html: true
    }
  )
}) 

What am I missing?
Does it require something if I want to use table in data-bs-content?

The bootstrap docs state:

By default, this component uses the built-in content sanitizer, which strips out any HTML elements that are not explicitly allowed

Meaning you need to add all table elements to the allowlist for this to function.
Example:
const allowList = bootstrap.Popover.Default.allowList;
allowList.table = [];
// tbody and thead are needed since they're automatically added by the browser if not present
allowList.tbody = [];
allowList.thead = [];
allowList.td = [];
allowList.tr = [];

var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
);
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(
    popoverTriggerEl,

    // options object as a second param
    {
      html: true,
      allowList: allowList,
    }
  );
});


Thank you so much! It worked! I understood it now, some elements should be manually added in the Allowlist.
